# Touching Child Timestamps while updating parent in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

W.r.t laravel doc [#Touching Parent Timestamps](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#touching-parent-timestamps)

```
class Comment extends Eloquent 
  {

    protected $touches = array('post'); // my concern with "touches"

    public function post()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo('Post');
    }

 }
```

so , when a Comment model is updated,automatically touch the updated_at timestamp of the owning Post.

I have a situation where i need to make it reverse , like when Post update automatically update comment's update_at for that post.

Is there  anyway to make this operation using Eloquent ORM ?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I am facing the same issue, and am just now beginning to research it.

Comment: Nope , if you get any solution let me know once.

Comment: I ended up going a completely different route, which no longer required updating all child records. Instead I'm using a VIEW to generate dynamic columns, instead of storing them on the child records as I wanted to before.